# Amazon cloudfront giving different assets for different user?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront

I am having following folder structure in rails app.

```
|-assets
  |-javascript
    |-lib
        bootstrap.js
        jquery.js
    application.js
  |-styleesheet
     |-lib
       bootstrap.js
  application.js
```

the static assets are hosted in cloudfront by diffreent people I don't know how it was done.

I have given the following config in production.rb.

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.compile = true
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'cloudfront url'
```

In view Page it will be like this:

```
<%[application,lib/bootstrap].each do |css_url| %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag css_url%>
<%end%>

<%[application,lib/bootstrap,lib/jquery].each do |js_url| %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag js_url%>
<%end%>
```

When deployed in production and for the first request it will compile assets folder and store them in cache. for subsequent request it will take from cache.But every time I host and make first request cache generated for only some files, not for all the files.

Comment: Which assets (fingerprint and names) users should download are served by your app? Are all users being told to download the same assets? Show us more on your *cloudfront* setup. Cloudfront simply servers or not (with an error) an asset requested by a user, but it's rails that tells the user the URL for that asset)

Comment: @Leito Sorry Thats where we got stuck Rails setup and cloudfront setup done by diffrent people I don't have access to that. I want to make sure that no error from my side. I updated the question with the config data.Please go through it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but please ensure that both users are receiving the same fingerprints in the files. If the fingerprints are not the same that it is likely an error not with cloudfront but something is wrong with your rails application.

The most likely cause for this error is that some multiple application workers are running (some serving older assets and some newer).

If the above does not help you solve the problem, please update with the specifics of your rails setup - caching layer, load balancer, application server etc.

Comment: I updated my question.The problem is setup of application handled by different people. We don't have any files regarding that.